# How do i check for missing vowels, consonants and numbers in a text given by the user?

Tags: javascript

I need help to check what vowels, consonants and numbers are missing in a text given by the user.Is there a way to do that?

For example: The user inputs the string 'Hello, World 123', the only vowels are: e and o, and the consonants are h, l, d, w, the numbers are 123, the program has to determine which vowels, consonants and numbers are missing from the string, for example: the missing vowels are: a, i, u, the missing numbers are: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and the missing consonants are: well, the rest of the consonants from the alphabet that are missing in the string

Comment: What do you mean by missing? Unless you know what words are supposed to be in the text, how can you tell what's missing?

Comment: You already asked this—with code—and removed the post before I could answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that - you don't show what you have tried (**which you should do, of course**).

Here's a way that could be used:

```js
function checkMissing(s) {
  let consonents = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
  let vowels = "aeiou";
  let numbers = "0123456789";
  s.split("").forEach(function(letter) {
    vowels = vowels.replace(letter, "");
    consonents = consonents.replace(letter, "");
    numbers = numbers.replace(letter, "");
  })
  return {vowels, consonents, numbers};
}
let missing = checkMissing("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz");
console.log("Missing vowels: " + missing.vowels);
console.log("Missing consonents: " + missing.consonents);
console.log("Missing numbers: " + missing.numbers);
```

And, I'm sure that there are more elegant ways to achieve this.